# Change ColVis Style in Datatable Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to give background color for 'Hide/Show columns' label in ColVis.js file where I need to do the change?

Comment: Hi, please explain better what you need. Possible add a bit of code here or in www.jsbin.com or in www.jsfiddle.com, you need to provide more information for the community to help.

Comment: $('#tblAssodetails').dataTable({
        "bFilter": false,
        "bInfo": true,
        "sScrollY": "300px", 
        "sScrollX": "690px",                      
        "bScrollCollapse": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "sDom": 'C<"clear">lfrtip'     ,           
        "aoColumnDefs": [{"bVisible": false, "aTargets": [9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32] });

Comment: i'm using above code in view page and using ColVis.js file

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can edit the css for the button in extras/ColVis/media/css/ColVis.css

```
.ColVis_Button {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 3px;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #fff; /* here */
    border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
    cursor: pointer;
    *cursor: hand;
}
```

Can't really see a way to do this using the api or options.

I suppose you could do this:

```
$('.ColVis_Button').css("background-color", "red");
```

Comment: instead of css change is there any possibility to change in view page jquery,i.e,using this,$('#example').datatable({});

Comment: is it possible to show the Columns in that 'ColVis_Button' in ascending order?

Comment: It seems to show the columns in order of the columns on the grid, I can't see an easy way to change this order unless you change the order of your grid columns :(

Answer (score 0):

These button styles are all CSS defined already. Just change the CSS in the ColVis CSS file that defines them.

This *is* the official and proper way because these are *styles*.

> instead of css change is there any possibility to change in view page
>   jquery,i.e,using this,$('#example').datatable({});

You don't change it in the datatable init because that is JS that modifies the ColVis JS params and controls the plugins functionality i.e. not how it looks.